# Javascript в Android

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

Подскажите пожалуйста...

Подключаю js, html, css, для webview нижним кодом.
Картинки,  js и подпапок, стили, всё работает.

```
<img src="file:///android_asset/img/image1.png">
```

```
WebView web = findViewById(R.id.webView);
WebSettings webSettings = web.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```

Но проблема уже дальше, Javascript работает на некоторых версиях api некорректно, начиная где-то с 16 по 21. На некоторых работает отлично. Да ещё, используется Javascript ES6. Что нужно сделать, чтобы работала на всех версиях? Именно проблема в js, либо webview...

Comment: Вы в самой Android Studio этот JS не можете запустить? Вопрос риторический. Уберите ненужные теги и исправьте заголовок, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поправьте меня, если я ошибаюсь.
С API 21 `WebView` это теперь отдельный пакет, который обновляется независимо от системы. А все предыдущие версии `WebView` были "вшиты" в систему, поэтому обновить их не предоставляется возможным. И соответственно, конечно, современные методы могут не работать!

Comment: То есть при использовании js, html и css лучше использовать минимальную сборку от API 21?

Comment: @Sergoi, либо да, либо писать код под WebView десятилетней давности, либо два варианта и ветвить по уровню API. Стоит ли на это тратить время думайте сами.